# Laplace Transformations of $\left(\frac{\cos \sqrt t}{\sqrt t}\right)$ and $\left(\sin \sqrt t\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals, laplace-transform

> Find the Laplace transforms of the following:
>
> 1.$\left(\dfrac{\cos \sqrt t}{\sqrt t}\right)$,
>
> 2.$\left(\sin \sqrt t\right)$.

Well, in the first, I used the cosine series expansion and solved the problem.
But in the next one, I used the same logic, but didn't get the answer as expected.

Please explain.  Can question 2  be obtained from question 1?

---

Batominovski's edit:

> Here is how to solve question 1.  Using $\cos(\theta)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!}\theta^{2k}$, we have
> $$\cos(\sqrt{t})=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!} t^k,$$
> so
> $$\frac{\cos(\sqrt{t})}{\sqrt{t}}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!}t^{k-\frac12}.$$
> Therefore
> $$f(s)=\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(\sqrt{t})}{\sqrt{t}}e^{-st}dt=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\int_0^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!}t^{k-\frac12}e^{-st} dt.$$
> Thus, for $s>0$, by setting $u=st$, we have
> $$f(s)=\int_0^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!}\frac{1}{s^{k+\frac12}}\int_0^\infty u^{\left(k+\frac12\right)-1}e^{-u}du.$$
> Therefore,
> $$f(s)=\frac1{\sqrt{s}}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!}\left(\frac{1}{s}\right)^k\Gamma\left(k+\frac12\right).$$
> But $\Gamma\left(k+\frac12\right)=\frac{(2k-1)!!}{2^k}\sqrt{\pi}$, so
> $$f(s)=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{s}}\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{(2k-1)!!}{(2k!)}\left(\frac{1}{2s}\right)^k,$$
> so
> $$f(s)=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{s}}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\left(\frac{1}{4s}\right)^k=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{s}}e^{-\frac1{4s}}.$$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/609328/laplace-transform-of-sin-sqrtt/628085#628085

Comment: ..but I need the solution .. by my series expansion, by using direct Laplace formulae :) ..

Comment: I see you are new to Math.SE.  Here's the deal: 1) If you want something done a certain way, say so in the problem statement; we are not mind-readers.  2) Is this for homework?  If it is, please be honest and say so.  It should affect how people will react to and respond to your question.  3) Avoid using words like "help" or "need" in the title or problem statement.  Keep in mind that people do this for fun, not because they are here to serve you.

Comment: @RonGordon Sir, I apologize for my mistakes, and will keep your suggestions in mind.Also,

Comment: @RonGordon Also, I never told that I didn't try doing the problems and misused SE for completion of homeworks. I mentioned the method what I tried. It's just that I got stuck. And it was obvious that I would expect the solution close to my method. I apologize. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you have :
$$( \sin ( \sqrt t))'=\frac 1 2\frac {\cos ( \sqrt t)}{ \sqrt t}$$
And
$$\mathscr {L} \{f'(t)\}(s)=s\,\mathscr {L} \{f(t)\}(s)-f(0)$$
Therefore:
$$\mathscr {L} \{(\sin ( \sqrt t))'\}(s)=s\,\mathscr {L} \{\sin ( \sqrt t)\}(s)$$
$$\mathscr {L} \left \{\frac 1 2\frac {\cos ( \sqrt t)}{ \sqrt t} \right \}(s)=s\,\mathscr {L} \{\sin ( \sqrt t)\}(s)$$
$$\boxed {\mathscr {L} \left \{\frac {\cos ( \sqrt t)}{ \sqrt t} \right \}(s)=2s\,\mathscr {L} \{\sin ( \sqrt t)\}(s)}$$