# What is the Laplace Transform of $f(x) = \sin(a \sqrt{x})$, a-parameter

Tags: integration, laplace-transform

What is the Laplace transform for function:

\begin{equation}
f(x) = \sin(a \sqrt{x})?
\end{equation}

I tried a lot of variations, but still, not sure how to solve it with the a-parameter. Is it maybe possible to solve without the Gamma function?

Comment: What have you tried? This would be easier to do with cosine instead of sine.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have to solve it with sinus. I tried using integral from the definition but it is really hard to get anything...

Comment: You need to prove $\int_0^\infty\sin(a\sqrt{x})e^{-sx}\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}as^{-3/2}e^{-a^2/(4s)}$ for $a,\,s>0$. Which techniques do you know for computing Laplace transforms? Could you edit your question to show what happened when you tried them?

Comment: Yes, I know the result, but I got stuck while doing integral by parts

Comment: Do you want to use some property or only calculate the integral?

Comment: I just want to know how to do this transform (if it is possible- without Gamma function)

Comment: you can use this posts https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3530529/laplace-transformations-of-left-frac-cos-sqrt-t-sqrt-t-right-and-lef?noredirect=1&lq=1 ,https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1434918/compute-laplace-transform-of-frac-cos-sqrt-t-sqrt-t?rq=1

Comment: but how to do it with parameter a?

Answer (score 3):

Using the posts that I suggest we have
$$( \sin ( a\sqrt t))'=\frac a 2\frac {\cos ( a\sqrt t)}{ \sqrt t}$$
And
$$\mathscr {L} \{f'(t)\}(s)=s\,\mathscr {L} \{f(t)\}(s)-f(0)$$
Therefore:
$$\frac{a}{2s} \mathscr {L} \left\{\frac {\cos ( a\sqrt t)}{ \sqrt t} \right\}(s)=\,\mathscr {L} \{\sin ( a\sqrt t)\}(s)$$
now
\begin{align*}
\mathscr {L} \left\{\frac {\cos ( a\sqrt t)}{ \sqrt t} \right\}(s) & = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac {\cos ( a\sqrt t)}{ \sqrt t} e^{-st} dt \\
& x = a \sqrt{t} \\
& = \frac{2}{a} \int_{0}^{\infty} \cos(x) e^{-sx^2/a^2} dx
\end{align*}
now let
$$
I(b) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \cos(bx) e^{-sx^2/a^2} dx
$$
using Feynman trick
\begin{align*}
I(b)' & = -\int_{0}^{\infty} x \sin(bx) e^{-sx^2/a^2} dx \\
& \text{use i.b.p}  \\
& = 0 - \frac{a^2}{2s} b \int_{0}^{\infty} \cos(bx) e^{-sx^2/a^2} dx \\
& =  -b\frac{a^2}{2s} I(b) \\
I(b)' & = -b\frac{a^2}{2s} I(b) \\
\frac{I(b)'}{I(b)} & = -b\frac{a^2}{2s} \\
\vdots & = \vdots \\
I(b) & = \dfrac{\sqrt{{\pi}}\,a}{2\sqrt{s}} e^{-b^2 a^2 / 4s} \\
I(1) & = \dfrac{\sqrt{{\pi}}\,a}{2\sqrt{s}} e^{- a^2 / 4s} \\
\end{align*}
we replace what we were looking for
\begin{align*}
\mathscr {L} \left\{\frac {\cos ( a\sqrt t)}{ \sqrt t} \right\}(s) & =\frac{2}{a} I(1) \\
& = \frac{2}{a} \dfrac{\sqrt{{\pi}}\,a}{2\sqrt{s}} e^{- a^2 / 4s} \\
& = \dfrac{\sqrt{{\pi}}\,}{\sqrt{s}} e^{- a^2 / 4s}
\end{align*}
Finally we have to
\begin{align*}
\frac{a}{2s} \mathscr {L} \left\{\frac {\cos ( a\sqrt t)}{ \sqrt t} \right\}(s) & = \frac{a}{2s} \dfrac{\sqrt{{\pi}}\,}{\sqrt{s}} e^{- a^2 / 4s} \\
& = \dfrac{a\sqrt{{\pi}}\,}{2s^{3/2}} e^{- a^2 / 4s}
\end{align*}

**Edit**

First we use the following property
$$ \mathscr {L} \{f'(t)\}(s)=s\,\mathscr {L} \{f(t)\}(s)-f(0)$$
Then, since the integral is difficult to calculate, we use the Feynman trick, you can see this video ( very similar) to understand how it works https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YO38MCdj-GM&t=538s. Now $I(b)$ is
$$
I(b) = \int_{0}^{\infty} cos(bx) e^{-sx^2/a^2} dx
$$
and
$$
I(1) = \int_{0}^{\infty} cos( x) e^{-sx^2/a^2} dx
$$
How does the $\pi$ number appear? Let's see, we have the following differential equation
$$
I(b)' = -b \frac{a^2}{2s}I(b)
$$
can be solved intuitively (is a function of $b$)
\begin{align*}
    I(b)' & = -b \frac{a^2}{2s} I(b)\\
    \frac{I(b)'}{I(b)} & = -b \frac{a^2}{2s}\\
    \int \frac{I(b)'}{I(b)} db & =\int  -\frac{b a^2}{s} db \\
    ln(I(b)) & = -\frac{b^2 a^2}{4s}  + C_1 \\
    I(b) &  = e^{-\frac{b^2 a^2}{4s}} C_2
\end{align*}
To find the value of $C_2$ we do the following
\begin{align*}
    I(0) &  = e^{-\frac{0^2 a^2}{4s}} C_2 \\
    I(0) & = C_2 \\
    \int_{0}^{\infty} cos(0 \cdot x) e^{-sx^2/a^2} dx & = C_2\\
    \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-sx^2/a^2} dx  & = C_2 \\
    \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{- \left( \sqrt{s} x/ a \right)^2} dx  & = C_2 \\
    \frac{a}{\sqrt{s}} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{- u^2} du  & = C_2 \\
    \frac{a}{\sqrt{s}} \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}  & = C_2 \\
\end{align*}
Finally we have
$$
I(b) = e^{-\frac{b^2 a^2}{4s}} \frac{a}{\sqrt{s}} \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} 
$$

Comment: which property did you use?And what is I(1) and I(b)? And from where we wnow that I(b) consist pi number?

Comment: I'm going to make an edit to the answer explaining that.

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: why in 3rd line we have \frac{2}/{2s}?