# Laplace Transform of Power

Tags: laplace-transform, complex-integration

I've come across the following derivation, for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124870/laplace-transform-of-t1-2-and-t-1-2), for the following Laplace transform of a power:

$$\mathcal L \{ t^a \} = \frac {\Gamma(a+1)}{s^{a+1}}$$

For $\operatorname{Re}(a) > -1, \operatorname{Re}(s)>0$. The proof I've seen does the following:

$$\mathcal L\{t^a\} := \int_0^{\to +\infty}t^a e^{-st} \, \mathrm dt$$

$$ = s^{-1} \int_0^? \left({\frac u s}\right)^a e^{-u}\, \mathrm du$$

and so on.

The upperbound of the integral is what I'm questioning. The proofs I've seen have $\infty$ in the upper bound, but I don't see how you can replace the complex number $st$ with a real number $u$ without making the bounds of the integral complex. But that would turn the Riemann integral into a contour integral! How is that allowed? Is the proof wrong?

Comment: As Dr.MV said you need some complex-analysis theorems for showing that $\int_0^\infty t^a e^{-st}dt = s^{-a-1} \int_0^\infty t^a e^{-t}dt= s^{-a-1} \Gamma(a+1)$ (whenever both converge, that is $Re(s) > 0,Re(a) > -1$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $s=\sigma+i\omega \in \mathbb{C}$, where $\sigma>0$ and $\omega \in \mathbb{R}$.

Let $I(a,s)$ be given by the integral

> $$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\int_0^\infty t^ae^{-st}\,dt=\lim_{L\to \infty}\int_0^L t^ae^{-st}\,dt}\tag 1$$

Now, enforcing the substitution $z=st$ in the integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$ reveals

$$\int_0^L t^ae^{-st}\,dt=\frac{1}{s^{a+1}}\int_0^{L\sigma+iL\omega}z^ae^{-z}\,dz \tag2$$

---

Next, we move to the complex plane.  Let $f(z)=z^ae^{-z}$.  If $a$ is not an integer, then $z^a$ is multivalued and has a branch point at $z=0$.  If we cut the plane along the negative real axis, then $z^a$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{z|\text{Re}(z)\le 0, \text{Im}(z)=0\}$.

---

Using Cauchy's Integral Theorem, we have

$$\oint_C z^ae^{-z}\,dz =0 \tag 3$$

where $C$ is a closed contour, comprised of $(i)$ the line segment from $0$ to $L\sigma$, $(ii)$  the line segment from $L\sigma$ to $L\sigma+iL\omega$, and $(iii)$ the line segment from $L\sigma+iL\omega$ to $0$.  (We also need to deform the contour around the branch point, but the contribution to the integral can be made arbitrarily small).

Therefore, we can write $(3)$ as

$$\int_0^{L\sigma}z^ae^{-z}\,dz+\int_{L\sigma}^{L\sigma+iL\omega}z^ae^{-z}\,dz+\int_{L\sigma+iL\omega}^0 z^ae^{-z}\,dz=0 \tag 4$$

As $L\to \infty$, the second integral on the left-hand side of $(4)$ approaches zero.  Therefore, letting $L\to \infty$ in $(4)$ yields

$$\int_0^{\infty}t^ae^{-t}\,dt=\lim_{L\to \infty}\int_0^{L(\sigma+i\omega)}z^ae^{-z}\,dz \tag 5$$

Putting together $(1)$, $(2)$, and $(5)$ yields the coveted equality

> $$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\int_0^\infty t^ae^{-st}\,dt=\frac{1}{s^{a+1}}\int_0^\infty t^ae^{-t}\,dt}$$

And we are done!

Comment: Math is beautiful! Thank you!

Comment: Why is the integral along the ray, the second integral on the LHS of (4), tending to zero? Can I use the FToC?

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  And math is beautiful.  -Mark

Comment: The second integral goes to zero because of the exponentially decaying integrand.

Comment: I graphed the integrand by fixing $a$ and $s$ and in fact the "naive" contour of $\operatorname{Re} + i \operatorname{Im}$ doesn't produce a straight line from the origin to $L\sigma + i L \omega$, it spirals out and then spirals in again. We can use Cauchy-Goursat anyway, because the curve is closed, but it's not simple.

Comment: Oh, but the spiral intersects the imaginary axis. Is that a problem?

Comment: @GFauxPas I don't understand your comments.  The contour $C$ is comprised of straight line segments by design.  There is no spiral.  -Mark

Comment: @Mark the example I'm looking at is $t^{-.5-i}\exp(-(1+i)t)$, with the parameterization $\theta(t) = t$

Comment: So, in the development herein, we have $s=1+i$ so that $\sigma =1$ and $\omega =1$.  Then, the contour $C$ goes from $0$, to $L$ to $L+iL$ and returns to $0$ (again, we actually have a small arc around the branch point, but this doesn't contribute to the result as the arc length goea to $0$).  The integrand is holomorphic in and on $C$.  So, what is the issue?

Comment: I was just looking at the "naive" curve traced out by  just parameterising the integrand and choosing an interval $t \in (0..L]$. But since the integrand is analytic, we can choose any contour that begins and ends at the points of interest, is that right?

Comment: Cauchy's Integral Theorem is valid for any simple rectifiable contour $C$ such that $f$ is analytic in and on $C$.  So, we want to choose a contour that is comprised of the straight line path from $0$ and $\sigma L$ and another one that has a straight line path from $0$ to $sL$.  We choose then to close with a contour such that it ia easy to show that as L\to \infty$, its contribution goes to $0$.